# Is the ZendFramework Security Advisory ZF2018-01 only an issue for IIS servers

Tags: iis, zend-framework2

After reading about the security advisory here:
https://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2018-01

And the fix applied to zend-http here:
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-http/releases/tag/release-2.8.1

I am trying to confirm that this bug only affects servers running IIS?

> This release modifies how Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request marshals the
>   request URI. In prior releases, we would attempt to inspect the
>   X-Rewrite-Url and X-Original-Url headers, using their values, if present.
>   These headers are issued by the ISAPI_Rewrite module for IIS (developed by
>   HeliconTech). However, we have no way of guaranteeing that the module is what
>   issued the headers, making it an unreliable source for discovering the URI. As
>   such, we have removed this feature in this release of zend-http.

Is my understanding correct - is this an IIS only exploit?

Comment: It only gives an example of IIS, but the vulnerability can apply to other web servers. Zend has its own support services, so if you need to confirm that, go to the vendor, https://framework.zend.com/learn/support-and-consulting

Answer (score 0):

No, the bug affects all webservers!

The issue is that the faulty code assumes that if those headers are set, they are set by this IIS module and 'trusts' these headers.

However those headers can be set e.g. by a malicious proxy, making them appear on requests to any webserver when the faulty code would still 'trust' them as if the IIS module set them.